# Reduce data transfer in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, data-transfer

How to reduce data transfer in my website which is hosted in AWS using ec2instance & nginx.

I tried the free tier but received a bill charged for data transfer that exceeded their limit.
would like a way other than VPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data Transfer** is charged for traffic going from AWS to the Internet.

Therefore, if people on the Internet are accessing your website (or retrieving files from your S3 bucket), it will generate a charge for Data Transfer.

To reduce Data Transfer costs, you will need to **reduce the amount of data transferred to the Internet**. For example, you could use a free [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/plans/free/) account to cache content. This way, whenever somebody goes to your website they would hit CloudFlare instead and it can serve the traffic instead of AWS. This is great for *static* content but won't help with *dynamic* content.